# OLS regression using varying holding period returns against 10 year yield?

Tags: regression

Can I run an OLS regression using varying holding periods for a stock?

I want to find the relationship between returns of stock x and the 10 year treasury yield, but I want to find what happens if for the regression I use 1 month, 2 month, and 3 month holding period returns for stock x.

If I run three OLS regressions (one for 1 month, one for 2 month, and one for 3 month holding period returns of stock x), will my regression coefficients have meaning? If so, how do I interpret each meaning in words?

Comment: Hi: Since no one else commented, I'll just throw in my 2 cents. Your problems will be the same  as those when doing of any regression of Y on X. Is the relationship linear, is there missing variable bias, do the standard OLS conditions hold, is the relationship stable as time moves forward. But this is not just the case for your problem. It's the case when doing any type of OLS regression over time. Note that by using different holding periods, you're really using a different Y in each case so that has nothing to do with the issues I mentioned but it also brings up a myriad of issues.

Comment: We are saying if 10 year yield rises from month 1 to month 2 by 1% point, then I should expect the 5-month return of stock x to rise 2% points from month 1 to month 2. If so, then in month 2 I would be thinking of a 5-month holding period which is different than the 5-month period in month 1. The same thing goes for a 1 month holding period, though. If I’m a market participant wondering how exactly I can interpret this, what’s the best way to word it assuming I always hold stock x for 5 months and then sell?

Comment: Hi Hans: I think that I see what you're doing sort of. Is the 10 year yield always on a monthly basis ? So, that it's only the response whose return window can change?

Comment: Exactly, yes. Only the holding period changes but we keep the 10 year yield at monthly yield so we can interpret with a familiar metric.

Comment: I’m really trying to see the sensitivity of returns, by holding period, to changes in the monthly treasury yield. Then I can say “1% rise in monthly treasury yield means a 2% rise in 1-month holding period return;” “1% rise in monthly treasury yield means a 5% rise in 3-month holding period return,” etc. Can I do that?

Comment: Hi Hans: Given my understanding, I don't think there's anything blatantly wrong with what you're doing but there's probably going to be a lot of noise in your results because a stock's return even over a few month's is EXTREMLY noisy. I would take the X holding period return ( for some stock ) and do a rolling type regression ( using that X ) and see how stable your results are. My guess is that you're results are going to illustrate quite a bit of instability.  To be honest, I'd be surprised if you even get the same sign ( of the estimated coefficient ) for each rolling period.

Comment: Just one other thing: If you include the market return on the RHS of your regression, that might help some with the instability. Basically, my point is that you'd have to get rid of all the effects on the stock's return before you can dig out the effect of the monthly yield. You've got a difficult problem. Maybe you want to look at "factor models". They're complex but that's what they try to do.